# For a large system that manages an entire school region, Relational or Non-Relational DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, relational-database, non-relational-database

I am building a large web app that will help a "region manager" to manage multiple schools in multiple districts.

In total, there are about 400,000 students & teachers.

On top of managing the obvious things like grades, etc. We will also have to manage attendance (daily).

I am used to building web apps at a smaller scale, which I deploy to Heroku. Given a system of this scale, should I be thinking about using a non-relational DB from now or should I just stick to PostgreSQL and do specific optimizations to ensure high-speed and data integrity?

If it isn't clear, the main concern is one of the system being so slow for managing so many records across so many tables - in a relational db system.

Also, what are some common optimizations I can do to ensure speed - if the recommendation is to use a relational DB? The biggest, most obvious one is using indexes on the most commonly accessed information.....anything else like that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. My team is split on what we should go with, so you guys will lend a useful voice in helping tip the balance :)

Comment: How much data do you expect to store? What kind of data will it be? How many tables?

Comment: It will be dozens of tables. Data will be of various kind (from regular strings to integers to boolean data). Pretty much any (and all) the type of data that you can imagine that the administrator of a region of school districts would want to store. From as granular as attendance for each student in each district to grades to who has paid full tuition to everything in between.

Comment: I just counted the number of tables in the old system (the original system was written in Rails 2.x - so I will be re-writing it from scratch). That system has 52 tables and I am told that they want to be able to capture more data. So, needless to say....it's a pretty involved dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick with postgresql. Why would something else be better?

With the little info you provided, I can guess your performance is going to probably come down to two things:

1. Proper [indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createindex.html) on the right columns
2. [Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) with rails and probably [redis](http://redis.io/)

---

Postgresql offers a datastore on disk. Caching pages with redis allows database queries and rendered parts of HTML to be cached in memory, as to avoid touching disk.

Comment: So this is what I had thought would be my best bet - but can you give me more details about why I would want to use Redis? You say I shud stick with PostgreSQL, but then you suggest redis? Is that just to store the cache?

Comment: @marcamillion see updates

Comment: So just so that I am not misusing & confusing terms...Redis could be an alternative to memcached? Or would it be used for something else?

Comment: @marcamillion sure either one will work, redis gives you more flexibility

Comment: Ok....I just wanted to make sure I understood where you were going. Yes, this is the architecture I had in mind. Thanks for confirming for me!

Answer (score 2):

Designing proper indexes is an important part of performance architecture, but you don't design indexes for *information*, you design indexes for *queries*.  And it has little to do with the choice between relational and non-relational database, since both demand you design "proper" indexes.  For more details, see my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

Comment: Thanks for this link. I will keep it in mind, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to performance, please be sure to consider security concerns. Not that NoSql databases are necessarily bad, but it's *different*.  Approaches to securing non-sensitive data can be different.

If you are storing any Personally Identifiable Information, weigh your options carefully, and if you're not sure what the differences are, go with what you know how to secure.

Also, it might not hurt to consider segregating data - some Relational and some not.  If you have the flexibility to architecture the system from scratch, whatever works best in your situation is what's right for you.

Suggested reading:

- http://www.darkreading.com/blog/232600288/a-response-to-nosql-security-concerns.html
- http://www.darkreading.com/database-security/167901020/security/news/232400214/does-nosql-mean-no-security.html
- http://www.bigdatarepublic.com/author.asp?section_id=2759&doc_id=256043

Suggested viewing:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEhy_SuCrYQ  (I love OWASP!)

Comment: There are good articles highlighting the ***positive*** of NoSql security but all of the ones I'm finding now require registration.  Sorry.  It's not all bad.  I'm just saying it's different, and in your situation I'll bet my hat there will be plenty of sensitive data.

Comment: You are very right. There is a bunch of sensitive data - at least, data that would be annoying if it got into the wrong hands.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook runs [MySQL](https://www.facebook.com/MySQLatFacebook). I don't know if 400K people means 400K users for this system: I don't think so, but still Facebook is orders of magnitude greater and uses MySQL.

Here is the fact: scaling is hard. If a NoSQL backend was enough to scale easily, noone nowadays would really start with a relational database, don't you think? I know this is not really an *answer* to your question, but I think there is simple *no answer* to this.

Use whatever you are comfortable with, use what excites you most, use what you think you'll be using for the next years, or use what you think it's easy to buy support for. Don't care *scalability* in the account for this choice, because until you face a problem you can't know how to solve. You can't even know if it exists altogether.

BTW, there are lots of considerations about fault tolerance, caching and other things which will have a way greater impact on your performance than SQL vs NoSQL. BTW, not all relational database engines are the same (neither all of NoSQL datastores are...)